# How to make infinite scroll on Next.js static page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'm making portfolio using Next.js and count of projects on page is big enough. I want to start loading images when they get into the current viewport. Such scenario works well with default placeholder prop of next/image.

I'm using custom placeholder (skeleton) component for my images (placeholder is hided when runs onLoadingComplete image prop). If I used SSR then algorithm is clear but with SSG I've reached a dead end.

Will be happy to any advices!

**My image component code:**

```
import Placeholder from './placeholder';

const ImageRenderer = ({ url, alt, layout, objFit, width, height }) => {
    const [isImageLoaded, setIsImageLoaded] = useState(false); // loading state

    return (
        <>
            {!isImageLoaded && <Placeholder />}
            <StyledImage
                src={url}
                alt={alt}
                width={width}
                height={height}
                layout={layout}
                objectFit={objFit}
                onLoadingComplete={() => setIsImageLoaded(true)} // runs when next/image is loaded
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

Placeholder is just div with higher z-index.

Comment: _"If I used SSR then algorithm is clear but with SSG I've reached a dead end"_ - can you clarify why SSG would be any different than SSR for your use case? Also, can you show us a code example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @juliomalves With SSR I can fetch some number of images each time when current end of page is reached, but with SSG all images are fetched at build time and I don't know how to manage image displaying.

About my code example. It's very simple: getStaticProps for getting list of items, then I'm using image component with custom placeholder (added code of image component in my question text).

Comment: _"With SSR I can fetch some number of images each time when current end of page is reached,"_ - you can fetch images on the client-side when the end of the page is reached with SSG as well. Just make the request from the page/component code.

Comment: So, you suggest to statically render the first batch of content and next fetch data on client-side, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @andrewnosov you should mark an accepted answer here or if you still have an unanswered element of the original question, state it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `loading="lazy"` to your images. It is supported in modern browsers.

**Update:**
For videos you can use `preload="none"`.

Comment: I think it's already activated. According to documentation: "The loading behavior of the image. Defaults to lazy."

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `next/image`, which [by default](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization) will only load images as they enter the viewport (you can control that via the [lazyBoundary](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#lazyboundary) prop). SSG vs SSR does not affect this behavior.

Comment: I've checked network panel in Chrome DevTools and realized that images are loaded when they cross the screen (it's what about you said above). But what you can say about videos?

Comment: Depends what your question is about videos? I don't see anything about it in your post. But assuming it's "how to load videos efficiently", the answer is like images, just don't show things before the user is looking at them. Use the video element with preload attribute set to "metadata" or "none", and don't use autoplay attribute unless it's above the fold.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention the video cards. On my page there are projects with image or video cover. So I realized that Next.js images is so smart and loads only when they appear inside viewport, but what about video covers?

Comment: You can use intersection observer for videos.

Comment: I've just noticed there is a preload="none" tag for videos.

Comment: @CleverSkull yeah I mentioned it lol

Comment: My videos have autoplay so preload is ignored. So, I think intersection observer is possible solution for my case.